# How does boost::multi_index work with member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

If I have a boost::multi_index as follows,

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    employee,
    indexed_by<    
        hashed_unique<mem_fun<employee, std::string, &employee::getname> >,
        hashed_unique<mem_fun<employee, int, &employee::getage> >
    > 
> employee_set;
```

I understand that the objects of class "employees" that are inserted into this container are stored in such a way that it can be retrieved in O(1) time(as a hash map).

How will it be stored when the member variables(name, age) are updated during the course of the program(like maybe with something like setname or setage) and still be hashed using those values? Am I understanding something wrong?

TIA

-R

Comment: See "replace" and "modify" in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#iterator_access):

> The iterators provided by every index are constant, that is, the elements they point to cannot be mutated directly. This follows the interface of `std::set` for ordered indices but might come as a surprise for other types such as sequenced indices, which are modeled after `std::list`, where this limitation does not happen. This seemingly odd behavior is imposed by the way `multi_index_container`s work; if elements were allowed to be mutated indiscriminately, we could introduce inconsistencies in the ordered indices of the `multi_index_container` without the container being notified about it. Element modification is properly done by means of [update operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating) on any index.

In other words, you only have `const` access to your stored objects, unless you use the container's updating functions, at which point it can hook into the call and adjust the hashes on-the-fly.